In-memory Python library for workflows
I am trying to model a complex business process which is light on memory but has complex branching rules. I am looking for a lightweight Python library that can be used to create this business process as a workflow without the overhead of setting up scalable infrastructure to back the process. To put it another way I am looking for an in-memory alternative to airflow or AWS step functions. One feature that I would appreciate is being able to visualize the business process - so having a simple graphviz or similar wrapper would be a plus.
